# Neo4J fails building and throws following error

Tags: java, neo4j, nullpointerexception, lucene

I have been running my JAR successfully for long time which builds a Neo4J graph. All of a sudden today i received the following error. I need help in understanding the below exception. Thanks!

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.legacy.IndexType.queryForGet(IndexType.java:449)
        at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.legacy.IndexType$1.get(IndexType.java:66)
        at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.legacy.LuceneLegacyIndex.get(LuceneLegacyIndex.java:202)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.StateHandlingStatementOperations.nodeLegacyIndexGet(StateHandlingStatementOperations.java:1416)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.OperationsFacade.nodeLegacyIndexGet(OperationsFacade.java:1146)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.LegacyIndexProxy$Type$1.get(LegacyIndexProxy.java:68)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.LegacyIndexProxy.internalGet(LegacyIndexProxy.java:293)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.LegacyIndexProxy.get(LegacyIndexProxy.java:282)
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this solved. Actually, the database from which the `Neo4J` was pulling data had couple of null records which prevented lucene from indexing the records. I was using Neo4J community version which builds the node on single instance. Hence the nodes didn't build further. I simply put the data in those records and errors went.